# Example of getLastModifiedTime() method in java.nio.*.

Tags: java

In Java 1.7, I'd read there are direct method to get last modified time of a file but I cant figure out what values should i pass to the parameters of LinkOptions. I'd appreciate the Most Simple Example. Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Path file = ...
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime time = attrs.lastModifiedTime();
```

Java Doc [BasicFileAttributes#lastModifiedTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastModifiedTime%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

Or directly:

```
File file = new File(...);
FileTime time = Files.getLastModifiedTime(file.toPath());
```